# SQL Statement returning too many rows within the OR statement

Tags: sql-server

Afternoon

I have a select statement

```
select sc.[Actual Posting Date], sc.[Product Code]
from SalesCurrent sc
where sc.[Customer Account] = 'BLUF008'
and sc.[Accounting Branch] = 117
AND exists
(
 SELECT 1 
 FROM SIC_ProductDetails p
 WHERE p.SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = 61
       AND p.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code]
       OR p.SIC_SupplierProductCode = 
       (
        SELECT sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode 
        FROM SIC_SupplierProducts sp 
        WHERE sp.SIC_IdSupplier = 6
        AND sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code]
       )
)
```

that I wish to only select on the SIC_SupplierProductCode table if there is not a value forund in the SIC_ProductDetails tabl

Would this mean using a case as I am getting back too many rows. That is because of the OR statement I think. I just dont know how to write it.

I dont know how to write the IF statement

Comment: Your query doesnt make any sense, read your own query from bottom up, so you are saying is `sc.[Product Code]` doesnt exists means it is null in `SalesCurrent` table , join `SalesCurrent` table to `SIC_SupplierProductCode` on `[Product Code]` , really :S how you plan to do that if the values doesnt exists or its NULL.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this and I really am a little lost. I see that the select is wrong. that what I am query more. I will try and find the syntac for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try this query

```
  SELECT 
    sc.[Actual Posting Date],
    sc.[Product Code]
  FROM SalesCurrent sc
  INNER JOIN SIC_ProductDetails p ON p.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code] AND p.SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = 61
  INNER JOIN SIC_SupplierProducts sp ON sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code] AND sp.SIC_IdSupplier = 6
  WHERE sc.[Customer Account] = 'BLUF008' AND sc.[Accounting Branch] = 117
```

Comment: I am still struggling. I only want to go to the SIC_SupplierProduct Table if there is not a value in the SIC_SupplierProduct table. The sql seems to be checking both tables.

Comment: Thank you @Ganesan! a great help and an evening of reading up for me!!

Answer (score 1):

May be you need one more parenthesis for `OR` condition

```
SELECT 1
FROM   SIC_ProductDetails p
WHERE  p.SIC_IdSupportedInitiative = 61
       AND ( p.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code] --here
              OR p.SIC_SupplierProductCode = (SELECT sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode
                                              FROM   SIC_SupplierProducts sp
                                              WHERE  sp.SIC_IdSupplier = 6
                                                     AND sp.SIC_SupplierProductCode = sc.[Product Code]) ) --here
```